# Rails - Using fog to connect to KVM

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We are currently trying to connect with our rails app to a remote KVM server with gem 'fog' + 'ruby-libvirt'

Following this good documentation : [libvirt-fog-provider](http://jedi.be/blog/2011/09/13/libvirt-fog-provider/)

```
require 'fog'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'
require 'pp'

client = Fog::Compute.new({
                     :provider => "libvirt" ,
                     :libvirt_uri => "qemu+ssh://root@perceval.boap.net/system?socket=/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock"
                   })

s1 = client.servers.all(:name => "demo2")
```

This code is working properly with a standard ruby file, we made the connection to KVM server
But when we put this same code in rails controller like this :

```
require 'fog'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'net/scp'

class VirtualMachinesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :connect_kvm
  def index
    head :no_content
  end

  private
  def connect_kvm
    client = Fog::Compute.new({
                                  :provider => "libvirt" ,
                                  :libvirt_uri => "qemu+ssh://root@perceval.boap.net/system?socket=/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock"
                              })
  end
end
```

Rails app display this error :

```
Call to virConnectOpen failed: internal error: received hangup / error event on socket):
  app/controllers/virtual_machines_controller.rb:28:in `connect_kvm'
```

Is rails appropriate to hold ssh sessions ? Am i missing something from rails purpose

Answer (score 0):

We found out why it wasn't working properly.

Don't forget to add in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```